# Best method of initialising Auto-Implemented Properties with null in c#?

Tags: c#

I'd like to take simple public properties and turn them into anonymous accessors, but some of my logic requires the initial values of the accessors/properties be `null`, can I rely on anonymous accessors to be null if I've not assign them a value?

currently :

```
public string XML = null;          // set XML or XMLPath to turn on XML stuff
public string XMLPath = null;
```

compared to :

```
public string XML {get; set;}
public string XMLPath {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. They are `null` by default. This is true also for fields. Actually, a automatic property also uses a field and that's why the default value of an automatic property is `null` (or `default(T)` to be more precise).

Answer (score 2):

Unassigned auto-implemented properties are defined to start with the default value for their type.  So reference types start `null`.

Comment: short, sweet and too the point, you answered first, others answers were good too.

Comment: @Nnoel: That really wasn't my intention. As I said, you should mark the answer as accepted that you liked the most.

Comment: well as I commented on yours, you showed me something new. so got to be fair, although poor timothy DOES have the lowest reputation. lol.

Comment: @Nnoel I wouldn't worry about voting for or against something based on the person's reputation score.

Answer (score 1):

New class fields are always initialized with nulls (except simple types which are initialized with them default values, like 0 for integer). You do not need to assign the null to them. It all aplies to auto implemented properties and fields in anonymouse object too.

Only method variables are not initialized, but as for them if you'll try to read them without initializing them first you'll get the compiler error first, so you don't need to worry here either.

Conclusion: C# always cares about not accessing uninitialized variables on compile-time, there is no chance that you will access variable that do not have default value assigned on runtime.